# How add spacing between each line of Cupertino Date Picker

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have increased the `FontSize` and now want to add space between each line. How to that because it doesn't look good.

Couldn't find a way.[image]

```dart
Container(
  height: 140.h,
  width: 335.w,
  child: CupertinoTheme(
    data: CupertinoThemeData(
    textTheme: CupertinoTextThemeData(
      dateTimePickerTextStyle: TextStyle(
         fontSize: 30.sp,
      )),
    brightness: Brightness.dark),
    child: CupertinoDatePicker(
      mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.time,
      initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
      onDateTimeChanged: (val) {
        setState(() {
          _chosenDateTime = val;
        });
      },
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: try adding itemHeight or something like that or please share your code to get solution.

Comment: Okay. I am sharing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Add `itemExtent:40.sp` properties in *CupertinoDatePicker* widget as per your requirement